# Using the result of a promise in Ember.RSVP.hash

Tags: ember.js, hash, promise

I've been pulling out my hair with this for a few hours now so I thought I'd just ask :)

In the model hook of my route, I'm grabbing the account ID from the session store. I'm also returning an Ember hash of layouts using a (presently) hard-coded ID:

```
model: function() {
  var accountId = this.get('session.currentUser').then(function(user) {
    return user;
  }).then(function(user) {
    return user.get('account');
  }).then(function(account) {
    var accountId = parseInt(account.get('id'));
    console.log(accountId); // outputs 2
    return accountId;
  });
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    layouts: this.store.query('layout', { account_id: 2 })
  });
},

/* {{log layouts}} in the template returns the correct list of layouts */
```

However, when I try and use the value of the first promise in the hash, as follows:

```
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  layouts: this.store.query('layout', { account_id: accountId })
});
```

I get the following error:

> You must pass a resolver function as the first argument to the promise constructor
>
> TypeError: You must pass a resolver function as the first argument to the promise constructor

I can almost understand this, as perhaps the accountID promise isn't resolved before the hash function is called.

But then I tried:

```
var _this = this;
var accountId = this.get('session.currentUser').then(function(user) {
  return user;
}).then(function(user) {
  return user.get('account');
}).then(function(account) {
  var accountId = parseInt(account.get('id'));
  console.log(accountId); // outputs 2
  return accountId;
}).then(function(accountId) {
  console.log(accountId); // outputs 2
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    layouts: _this.store.query('layout', { account_id: accountId })
  });
});
```

This does not give any errors, but {{log layouts}} in the template returns 'undefined'.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Where is this happening? In the model hook?

Comment: Sorry, yes in the model hook

Comment: I guess you return `accountId` in model hook. So, what about `{{log model.layouts}}` ?

Comment: Sorry if my original question was unclear - I've updated it. I'm actually trying to do all this in a model hook, should I not be?

Comment: why not just - 
  `var layouts =  _this.store.query('layout', { account_id: accountId }`

Comment: `accountId` is a promise, not a number! I suspect `this.store.query` doesn't accept that as an argument.

Comment: yeah but within the `.then` it should wait for the accountId and then use it to query the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the hash at the end, structure your promise the other way around:

```
var _this = this;
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  layouts: this.get('session.currentUser').then(function(user) {
      return user;
  }).then(function(user) {
      return user.get('account');
  }).then(function(account) {
      return parseInt(account.get('id'), 10);
  }).then(function(accountId) {
      return _this.store.query('layout', { account_id: accountId });
  })
});
```